# Dynamic Menu link Replacement Jquery

Tags: jquery, menu

I need to hide all list elements, but only show one at a certain time depending on the direction or button pressed by the nav bar.

I've tried this:

`$('ul li').hide().first().show();`

which shows me the first element in the list.

But now I need to take control of the list with navigation which I don't know how to do.

Basically, I need a menu that has more or less this layout:

```
< - prev           LINK1            next - >
```

So basically, id have a unordered list, so the html would be like this

```
<ul>
    <li>LINK1</li>
    <li>LINK2</li>
    <li>LINK3</li>
</ul>
```

So, I need to only display one at a time, and once the next or previous buttons are pressed it would "loop through" the list if it's at the end or start.

Comment: I have zero clue, I've tried using $(this).next().append(#container) 

Something like that, but It didn't work :(

Comment: If all you did was try `append()` you must not have spent much time cruising the jQuery documentation. Take a look at `animate()`, play with the CSS. Keep us updated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sechou/UmRph/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe these code can help you
http://jsfiddle.net/sechou/UmRph/7/

```
$("li").hide();   // hide every element first
$("li:first").show(); // only display the first one
var idx = 0;
$("nextbtn").click(function(){
     if(idx == $("li").size() -1)
          idx =0;
     else
          idx++;

     $("li").hide();
     $("li:eq("+ idx + ")").show();
});
$("prevbtn").click(function(){
     if(idx == 0)
          idx = $("li").size() -1;
     else
          idx--;

     $("li").hide();
     $("li:eq("+ idx + ")").show();
});
```

Comment: I can't get this to work :( is there anyway you can make a fiddle example? @Shih-En Chou?

Comment: First, I didn't know whole html in your case.
What I gave was just algorithm.

Comment: Your else statements are wrong, you've miss spelled function, had nothing to do with html.

Answer (score -1):

Please, If you're going to upload something, make sure it's correct.

Your syntax and spelling wasn't correct, for someone of my experience, It's very hard to nut out problems when things are wrong, thankyou for helping all the same, i still managed to get your code working after about 2 hours of fiddling...

```
var elem = '#collList li';    
$(elem).hide();
$(elem + ":first").show();
var count = 0;
$('#nextBtn').click(function() {
    if (count == $(elem).size() - 1) {
        count = 0;
    }
    else {
        count++;
    }
    $(elem).hide();
    $(elem + ":eq(" + count + ")").show();
});
$('#prevBtn').click(function() {
    if (count == 0) {
        count = $(elem).size() - 1;
    }
    else {
        count--;
    }
    $(elem).hide();
    $(elem + ":eq(" + count + ")").show();
});
```

Comment: We're not here to do the work for you. If somebody provides you with a starting point you should be grateful. If it takes a bit of work on your part to get it working you'll be better for it.

Comment: I don't know any of it, hence why I'm here to learn, how can one person learn if they're given the wrong documents.

Comment: One of the best ways to learn something is to fix what is broken. Learning takes a lot of work, and we're willing to help. But we're not going to do all the work for you. I'm just telling you how this place works.